# request.getAsync() only returns 1 parameters

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, node-request

I'm trying to get request to return the body of a .cert but using the .spread from bluebird seems to only return 1 parameters and not two like it should.

```
request.getAsync( {url: payload.publicKeyUrl, encode:null } )
    .spread( function(res, body){
        console.log(body);
    } );
```

This will throw an error that body is undefined. Response return the ENTIRE json format, including the cert in string format which messed with the structure.

I'm using request 2.67.0 and bluebird 3.1.1.
And this is the cert url: https://static.gc.apple.com/public-key/gc-prod-2.cer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bluebird 3.0 changes promisification to default to only using the first argument when performing promisification.

In your call to `Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"))` you need to pass a second parameter to indicate you're interested in all parameters `Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"), {multiArgs: true})`

Alternatively, you can use the `request-promise` package that does this for you with some other minor fixes (it uses bluebird internally).

Comment: Thanks! that was it but what do I specify to properly get the cert? Right now getting a string with all kinds of artefacts.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking there - but if you're having a hard time with the output request-promise is a more completely wrapped `request` so you might want to consider that since `request` is very quirky. Feel free to ask another (separate) question on the site about the cert issue (and explain it further since I don't understand it)